# Problem in openldap with TLS configuration

Tags: ldap, tls

I configured openldap with TLS, but when I tried to test it with following command, I receieve the error message:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect localhost:389 -showcerts
CONNECTED(00000005)
14041704935568:error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:s23_lib.c:177:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 320 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
---
```

I add -tls ption in this command but my output was

```
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
---
secure renegotiation is not supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
   Protocol: TLSv1 
...
```

Answer (score 0):

> I receieve the error message...

It looks like the service listening on `localhost:389` does not use SSL/TLS. The equivalent in the non-ldap world would be to use `openssl s_client` to connect over port 80 rather than port 443. In the case of port 80, there's no SSL/TLS and you will get a similar failure.

Have you tried port 636? I believe that LDAPS or Secure-LDAP. See, for example, [How to enable LDAP over SSL with a third-party certification authority](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321051).

Otherwise, you'll need to figure out how to make OpenLDAP start SSL/TLS on port 389.